# Calender View highlight

Tags: android, mobile, calendar

guys how can i do with CalenderView that the first day of every month will be in highlight or just in different color or even not the start of the month even highlight middle of the month

Answer (score 0):

First you should understand how to select a date, then highlight those dates .

Here is a Sample:

```
String date = "22/3/2014";
    String parts[] = date.split("/");

    int day = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
    int month = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
    int year = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);

    long milliTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
```

And now set the selected date in the calendar view by doing and further activities as your requirement:

```
mCalendarView.setDate (milliTime, true, true);
```